# mod_wsgi and multiple projects

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

tearing my hair out here trying to figure out why my two django projects are not being separately served ... it seems that the static files for whichever is accessed first become the defacto static files for both projects, or something to similar effect.

I'm attempting to serve two projects (which are actually different versions of the same original project - with different databases, and different physical locations), via two domain names off the same IP address. Initially I tried virtualhosts on multiple IP addresses (differentiated by port), but that failed. Unfortunately - I have exactly the same problem using virtualhosts with different domain names.

The virtualhost section of the Apache http.conf is as so:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin shane.brown@gmail.com
ServerName www.toastprojects.tk
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Python27/sites/Adaptwater/adaptwater/wsgi.py"
Alias /static/ "C:/Python27/sites/Adaptwater/static/"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:/Python27/sites/Adaptwater/static/">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Python27/sites/Adaptwater/adaptwater/">
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin shane.brown@gmail.com
ServerName toastprojects.power.on.net
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/git_clones/adaptwater/adaptwater/adaptwater/wsgi.py"
Alias /static/ "C:/git_clones/adaptwater/adaptwater/static/"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:/git_clones/adaptwater/adaptwater/static/">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/git_clones/adaptwater/adaptwater/adaptwater/">
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I've set up wsgi.py for each as so (with the absolute path corresponding to the particular project's location) :

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('C:/git_clones/adaptwater/adaptwater')
sys.path.append('C:/git_clones/adaptwater')
#os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "adaptwater.settings")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "adaptwater.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Running these on localhost through the dev server (and with nginx serving static files) at the same time works with no problem. And assuming I want to access the sites one at a time, and restart Apache - each works served externally on a solo basis. Anything obvious causing this problem?

Cheers, Shane

---

Update :

At this point I have to conclude that what I want to do cannot be done due to the less than perfectly happy marriage of mod_wsgi and the windows platform (I should have mentioned the platform - neglected to in my haste - windows 7 professional 64). I can't use WSGIDaemonProcess, and WSGIApplicationGroup must be set as global, and from what I've been able to glean from discussions relevant to this issue - that means I'm at a dead end.

I've managed to serve the second project with no weird settings hybridization using nginx & fastcgi instead ... as a stopgap. So far this combo has been treating me kindly.

The even less stellar option of nginx serving static files and proxy passing to the django dev server also works as a parallel arrangement for external serving. Have yet to try two nginx/fastcgi served versions of the project simultaneously - but I'll leave that as an exercise for another awesome day of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You must include your `<directory>` configuration directives within their corresponding `<virtualhost>` configuration directives.

Comment: Thanks! Will give that a red hot go.

Comment: This is from an old project, but should have everything you need to get going: [apache.conf](https://github.com/twoolie/ProjectNarwhal/blob/master/example_project/apache.conf)